# What is the "0G" terminal sequence

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have come across a lot of bash PS1 prompts like this `export PS1="\[\033[0G\]${PS_INFO} ${PS_GIT}${PS_TIME}\n${RESET}\$ "`

For some reason, virtualenv name printing was messing up in my terminal and was fine after I removed the `[\033[0G\]` from the beginning.

But what is the purpose of `[\033[0G\]`? Do I need it?

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to move the cursor to column 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [**`CHA`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_):

```
    CSI Ps G  Cursor Character Absolute  [column] (default = [row,1]) (CHA).
```

and moves the cursor to the first column of the current line.  A **0** is redundant (and happens to be treated identically with **1** for *numbers* like this).

Whether you need it or not depends on what else might be on the line.  Someone used that to make certain that the prompt begins in a known position.